# Magento index.php base url in admin issue

Tags: magento

In magento 1.8 front-end is working fine , but admin end is not working. E.g. the following URL

```
localhost/magento/index.php/admin/
```

is not working. However, this

```
localhost/magento/admin/
```

is working.

All admin pages contain index.php in base url and so 404 not found , when i am remove index.php from url manully , then again hit url in browser its works.

Comment: Highlighted the URLs

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an issue with your configuration.

Go to `System > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure)`

Here you should have localhost/magento and not localhost/magento/index.php